# How to set to window view in TexStudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio

In TexStudio, the default setting is that a tex file is displayed along with its pdf file on the same screen after compilation (F5). The pdf file can be viewed in a separate window after pressing the "Windowed View" button.

I wonder how to change the setting so that the pdf file is always viewed in a separate window after F5. Also, how to change the default zoom of the pdf file (current setting is 120%)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the default setting go in the menu `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio...`.

If you have not selected `Show Advanced Options`, there is a `PDF Viewer` selection box, from which one can selected between internal and external PDF Viewer, and embedded and windowed for the internal option. The option you select here will be the default on the next start of the software.

[image]

If you have selected `Show Advanced Options`, then the syntax is explicit presented. Add  `--embedded` to the end of the PDF viewer command to embed the PDF viewer. Without it, the viewer will be windowed.

[image]

About default zoom, just change your desired value in the `Internal PDF Viewer` tab.

[image]

To change it between windowed and embedded for the current document, just click the button on the right upper side of the viewer to switch between each form of presentation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The scaling seems only for the internal pdf viewer, not for the windowed viewer. Is there a way to change the default scaling for the windowed viewer?